Hardware Realization of Convolutional Encoder with rate R=1/2
For \$R=1/2\$ convolutional encoder with a generator matrix \$G(x)=[1+x^2+x^3 1+x+x^3]\$
1.draw the hardware realization of the encoder.

determine the convolutional matrix generator, G.

For the input sequence \$m=[1011011]\$ determine the coded output sequence.


Relevant Equations:  In the attachment, there's the drawing where G2 is the output of G(x) second entry above and G1 is the first output in the first output entry above. D is the shift register.
Is my drawing correct?
As for item 2. I don't see how to get the convolutional matrix G from G(X) above, section 3 is just ##mG##, i.e multiplication of the message vector by ##G## (multiplication of a vector with a matrix from left to the matrix.)
Thanks in advance!

My attempt at solution says it all.
OK, I think I get it now.
$$G_0=[11], G_1=[01],G_2=[10],G_3=[11]$$
So $$G=\begin{bmatrix}G_0& G_1& G_2& G_3\\
00 & G_0 &G_1 & G_2\\
00 & 00 & G_0 & G_1\\
00 & 00 & 00 & G_0\\\end{bmatrix}$$
Where I got G_i's as the coefficients of the respective polynomials.
Well, G is inifinite dimensional so this matrix should repeat itself endlessly.
